# Assignment with R's ompr or another optimization function

Tags: r, optimization, modeling

Wondering whether this can be solved with the `ompr` `R` `package` (or any other optimization `package`).

I have `n` treatments and `m` cell lines, and for each treatment:cell-line pair I ran an experiment where the readout is the sensitivity of the cell-line to the treatment.

Now I need to run a confirmatory experiment where I need to choose `i` treatments where for each I need to pick `j` sensitive and `j` non-sensitive cell lines (in my case `i` = 40 and `j` = 4). In this confirmatory experiment I'm running the treatments and cell lines on the same plate so my objective is to minimize the overall number of cell lines.

I'm wondering if this can be translated to terms of an [assignment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_assignment_problem) which the R `ompr` can solve?

Answer (score 4):

Given I interpreted your problem correctly I modelled it using `ompr`. If I understood you correctly you want to match a subset of treatments to cell lines. Each treatment should be matched to two sensitive cell lines and two non-sensitive cell lines. I further assume, that cell lines can be shared among treatments, otherwise there is no need to minimize the number of cell lines.

First of all we need to create the input data for the model. I use the notation you chose in your question.

```
# For testing I chose small numbers.
# Number of treatments
n <- 10
# Number of cell lines
m <- 10
# Number of treatments for confirmatory experiment
i <- 4

# simulation of treatment results
# a data.frame with a sensitivity result for each treatment/cell_line combination.
# the result is either TRUE (sensitive) or FALSE (not sensitive)
treatment_results <- expand.grid(treatment = 1:n, cell_line = 1:m)
treatment_results$result <- runif(nrow(treatment_results)) < 0.3
```

In addition I create two helper functions that will come in handy later when formulating the model.

```
# helper function to identify positive or negative 
# treatment/cell_line combinations in order to make the modelling easier to read
is_sensitive <- function(k, j) {
  purrr::map_lgl(j, function(j) {
    record <- treatment_results$treatment == k & treatment_results$cell_line == j
    treatment_results[record, "result"]
  })
}
is_not_sensitive <- function(k, j) {
  !is_sensitive(k, j)
}
```

Now the model. I added inline comments to describe the constraints/decision variables. Please use the most recent version of `ompr`.

```
library(ompr)
library(magrittr)
model <- MIPModel() %>%

  # 1 if treatment k is applied to cell_line j
  add_variable(x[k, j], k = 1:n, j = 1:m, type = "binary") %>%

  # 1 if treatment k is selected for confirmatory experiment
  add_variable(y[k], k = 1:n, type = "binary") %>%

  # 1 if cell_line j is used
  add_variable(z[j], j = 1:m, type = "binary") %>%

  # minimize the number of assigned cell lines
  set_objective(sum_expr(z[j], j = 1:m), direction = "min") %>%

  # we want to test i treatments
  add_constraint(sum_expr(y[k], k = 1:n) == i) %>%

  # each tested treatment has to have 2 sensitive and 2 non-sensitive cell lines
  # 2 sensitives
  add_constraint(sum_expr(x[k, j], j = 1:m, is_sensitive(k, j)) == 2 * y[k]
                 , k = 1:n) %>%
  # 2 not sensitives
  add_constraint(sum_expr(x[k, j], j = 1:m, is_not_sensitive(k, j)) == 2 * y[k]
                 , k = 1:n) %>%

  # last constraint is to mark cell lines as being assigned for the obj. fun.
  add_constraint(sum_expr(x[k, j], k = 1:n) <= n * z[j], j = 1:m)
```

Given the model, we can solve it using GLPK for example. Please note that the model might take a long time with the larger parameters.

```
# you can solve the model using GLPK for example
library(ompr.roi)
library(ROI.plugin.glpk)
result <- solve_model(model, with_ROI("glpk", verbose = TRUE))

# let's examine the solution
library(dplyr)
# this is the list of treatments selected for testing
filter(get_solution(result, y[k]), value > 0)$k

# this is the list of cell_lines selected for testing
filter(get_solution(result, z[j]), value > 0)$j

# the actual matching of treatment and cell_line is in the x variable
get_solution(result, x[k, j]) %>%
  filter(value > 0) %>%
  inner_join(treatment_results, by = c("k" = "treatment", "j" = "cell_line"))
```